# PHP conditional logic AND OR

Tags: php, if-statement, conditional-statements

small question. I have this code:

```
if($A || $B && $C)
```

This results in

```
if (($A) || ($B && $C))
```

Since AND has a higher precedence, i expected:

```
if (($A && $C) || ($B && $C))
```

Why is this not the case? Thanks

Comment: Well exactly _because_ AND has the higher precedence. Sounds like you might not have understood what that actually means …?

Comment: `5 + 2 * 6` is `17`, because `*` has higher precedence than `+`. You would not expect this to actually be `5 * 2 + 5 * 6` either, right?

Comment: @misorude thanks, I'm having a bad day:)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For less confusion, you can replace the `&&` and `||` operators respectively by *multiply* and *add* operators, they have the same predecence.

The logical operation `$A || $B && $C` *could* be translated in mathematical as `$A + $B * $C` (This is definitely not the same operation, but the predecence is similar)

You can't refactorize `$A + $B * $C` to `$A * $C + $B * $C`, however, you can rephrase the operation to `($A) + ($B * $C)`

Answer (score 1):

### `&&` has a higher priority than `||`

If you have a look into [operator precedence](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.precedence.php) you'll see that `&&` has a higher priority than `||`, however quoting from this documentation:

> Parentheses may be used to force precedence, if necessary.

So if you just use the code you expected instead, this'll give you the results you want:

```
if (($A && $C) || ($B && $C))
```